# QGuiApplication without display using QPainter and QPdfWriter

Tags: qt, fonts

I'm writing a Qt program that is meant to run without a display and will generate PDF files. For the PDF writing I'm using the QPdfWriter class with a QPainter object. I've already developed the PDF writing part of my program and that all works great (I'm able to draw lines/text/images no problem). My problem is in getting the program to run without a display AND get QPainter to draw text.

Originally I was using a `QApplication` object, but when run without a display I'd get the following output:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

I learned that I had to use a `QGuiApplication` object instead and pass in the arguments `-platform offscreen` to fix the display problem. However when I pass the arguments `-platform offscreen` I then loose my fonts used by `QPainter` and get the following output:

```
QFontDatabase: Cannot find font directory C:/Qt/5.9.2/msvc2013_64/lib/fonts.
Note that Qt no longer ships fonts. Deploy some (from http://dejavu-fonts.org for example) or switch to fontconfig.
```

I went to the `dejavu` website and downloaded the available fonts and am now loading the fonts using:

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("C:/Users/username/Downloads/dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37/ttf/DejaVuSans.ttf");
```

Now my PDF generation works and is able to use the font that is manually loaded. My problem is that I still get the error printout saying "QFontDatabase: Cannot find font......". This is pretty annoying seeing as though I've already loaded some fonts and everything is working. So my question is: **is there a way to turn this warning off?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line to the beginning of your `main()` to get rid of the warnings:

```
qputenv("QT_QPA_FONTDIR", "C:/Users/username/Downloads/dejavu-fonts-ttf-2.37/ttf");
```

Comment: Excellent, that fixed it. Also, as a note to others who come across this, when adding the `qputenv` line as @talamaki explained, there is no longer a need to use the `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont` call. The `qputenv` line replaces the `addApplicationFont` line.